# Instagram API to fetch pictures with specific hashtags

Tags: api, tags, instagram

I want to get all the pictures with a specific hash tag from Instagram using PHP. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, the Instagram API endpoint "tags" required OAuth authentication.

You can query results for a particular hashtag (snowy in this case) using the following url

It is rate limited to 5000 (X-Ratelimit-Limit:5000) per hour

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snowy/media/recent

Sample response

```
{
  "pagination":  {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1370433362010",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1370433362010",
    "next_min_id": "1370443976800",
    "min_tag_id": "1370443976800",
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snowy/media/recent?access_token=40480112.1fb234f.4866541998fd4656a2e2e2beaa5c4bb1&max_tag_id=1370433362010"
  },
  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  [
     {
      "attribution": null,
      "tags":  [
        "snowy"
      ],
      "type": "image",
      "location": null,
      "comments":  {
        "count": 0,
        "data":  []
      },
      "filter": null,
      "created_time": "1370418343",
      "link": "http://instagram.com/p/aK1yrGRi3l/",
      "likes":  {
        "count": 1,
        "data":  [
           {
            "username": "iri92lol",
            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_404174490_75sq_1370417509.jpg",
            "id": "404174490",
            "full_name": "Iri"
          }
        ]
      },
      "images":  {
        "low_resolution":  {
          "url": "http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/ecf272a2cdb311e2990322000a9f192c_6.jpg",
          "width": 306,
          "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail":  {
          "url": "http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/ecf272a2cdb311e2990322000a9f192c_5.jpg",
          "width": 150,
          "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution":  {
          "url": "http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/ecf272a2cdb311e2990322000a9f192c_7.jpg",
          "width": 612,
          "height": 612
        }
      },
      "users_in_photo":  [],
      "caption":  {
        "created_time": "1370418353",
        "text": "#snowy",
        "from":  {
          "username": "iri92lol",
          "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_404174490_75sq_1370417509.jpg",
          "id": "404174490",
          "full_name": "Iri"
        },
        "id": "471425773832908504"
      },
      "user_has_liked": false,
      "id": "471425689728724453_404174490",
      "user":  {
        "username": "iri92lol",
        "website": "",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_404174490_75sq_1370417509.jpg",
        "full_name": "Iri",
        "bio": "",
        "id": "404174490"
      }
    }
}
```

You can play around here :

https://apigee.com/console/instagram?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22get_tags_media_recent%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22tag-name%22%3A%22snowy%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D

You need to use "Authentication" as OAuth 2 and will be prompted to signin via Instagram.
Post that you might have to reneter the "tag-name" in "Template" section.

All the pagination related data is available in the "pagination" parameter in the response and use it's "next_url" to query for the next set of result.

Comment: How to get next page url? I mean get the next set of response in php or javascript?

Comment: Use the "next_url" in the response to query for further results. You can read more at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ "Pagination" section.

Comment: It looks like this endpoint is deprecated now.  The specific reply I received was: {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotAllowedError", "error_message": "This endpoint has been retired"}}

Comment: @JaspalSingh The link of apigee is no longer works

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible yet to search for content using multiple tags, for now only single tags are supported.

> Firstly, the Instagram API endpoint "tags" required OAuth authentication.

This is not quite true, you only need an API-Key. Just [register](http://instagram.com/developer/register/) an application and add it to your requests.
Example:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/userIdYouWantToGetMediaFrom/media/recent?client_id=yourAPIKey
```

Also note that the username is not the user-id. You can look up user-Id`s [here.](http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id)

A workaround for searching multiple keywords would be if you start one request for each tag and compare the results on your server. Of course this could slow down your site depending on how much keywords you want to compare.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look here in order to get started:
http://instagram.com/developer/

and then in order to retrieve pictures by tag, look here:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Getting tags from Instagram doesn't require OAuth, so you can make the calls via these URLs:

`GET IMAGES`
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token={TOKEN}`

`SEARCH`
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q={tag-query}&access_token={TOKEN}`

`TAG INFO`
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token={TOKEN}`