# Grab Instagram post dates based on hashtags

Tags: python, api, selenium, reference, hashtag

I am not very good on python code, but I am tasked to write a code to grab Instagram post dates based on a certain hashtag (I have approx 2000 hashtags). The purpose of my task is to find out how many time the certain hashtag was mentioned per day. Meaning when the application is started and search for the hashtag "#popcorn", any post with that hashtags should be automatically counted.

My question is that what is the process of doing this? or is there any service regarding my task? I heard about selenium, but if there are any examples that I can reference, it would be so much helpful.

Let me know what you guys think! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a url endpoint you can use for this in the developer api.

You can look at this post for reference: [Instagram API to fetch pictures with specific hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177428/instagram-api-to-fetch-pictures-with-specific-hashtags)